# Как удалить style из всех остальных button, кроме тех, на которые я только что нажал?

Tags: javascript

```
var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box')

for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
    box[i].addEventListener('click',function(event){
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
    })
}
```

Comment: Это значит, что у всех кнопок вначале есть стили, но после клика по одной из них стили всех кнопок, кроме нажатой, но если нажать на другую кнопку, то ни у одной из кнопок не должно остаться стиля?

Comment: да совершенно верно

Answer (score 1):

```js
let box = document.querySelectorAll(".box");

for (let i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
  box[i].addEventListener("click", highlight);
}

function highlight() {
  for (let i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
    box[i].style.backgroundColor = ""; // Удалить стили у всех элементов,
  }
  
  this.style.backgroundColor = "red";  // Добавить кликнутому элементу.
}
```

```css
.box { display: inline-block; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid red; cursor: pointer }
```

```html
<div class="box">00</div>
<div class="box">00</div>
<div class="box">00</div>
<div class="box">00</div>
```